# Internationalization for flash applications

Tags: apache-flex, flash, internationalization

I'm working with a flash application (non-flex), and I'd like to support internationalization. In flex there's a nice abstraction ResourceManager in which you provide resource bundles for each locale. Is there any equivalent for actionscript?

Comment: fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284772/internationalization-for-flex-flash-apps

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Globalization](http://www.servebox.org/actionscript-foundry/actionscript-foundry-documentation/building-localized-flex-applications/) package from AS Foundry?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself, but this one looks interesting:

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2005/12/actionscript_30_first_attempt.php

It's based on the GNU gettext implementation and tool chain.

Answer (score 1):

We created a nice little tool around gettext:

http://code.google.com/p/asgettext/

With this tool you can easily create multilingual application using a default internationalization tool.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to the suggested packages above, you may want to create and store all of your language content in database and then generate the resource bundle files.  This way you can have a central interface to manage it all but still enjoy the performance of resource bundles..

good luck!