# Internationalization for Flex/Flash Apps

Tags: django, apache-flex, flash, internationalization, gettext

What options are there for storing and accessing translated strings in a Flex/Flash application? Ideally, I would like to share translation data with my Django website's internationalization data. This leads me to believe that some version of `gettext` would be best. But what is the industry standard, and the best implementation and documentation?

> Related (but never answer-accepted, and old) post:
>
> [Internationalization for flash applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655845/internationalization-for-flash-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion localization with Flex is sort of ... unsatisfactory.
If you use the ResourceManager you can't work with the design view. Instead of "Hello" there would be something like "ResourceManager.get....."

A better solution is to use LocalizationMaps, which is sort of a mate extension:
http://mate.asfusion.com/news/flex-i18n-with-localizationsmaps-an-amazing-extension

Comment: +1: @hering: nice, this looks like it might play well with i18n in django - maybe i can even share content. could you contrast it at all with the alternate suggestion of LupoManager?

Comment: I don't know LupoManager as far as I know you could extract the strings which should be translated with LupoManager. This isn't possible with LocalizationMaps. So if you want to use the localizationMaps you have to know what strings you want to translate and you also need to have resources.properties.
But if you use LupoManager you also have strings in your application like "{resourceManager.get[TYPE]('[BUNDLE]','[KEY]')}". You could use LupoManager to extract the strings an LocalizationMaps to handle the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [Lupo Manager](http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/88)

Comment: +1: @michael: nice, this looks like it might play well with i18n in django - maybe i can even share content. could you contrast it at all with the alternate suggestion of Mate/AFusion?

Comment: Eruciform: I do not play with both Lupo Manager and Mate, so I can't give any comment on them.  As I know, Lupo Manager is just a tool to help you to create the resource bundle more easily and Mate is a framework, so you need to decide do you want to use a framework for your project.

Answer (score 0):

For Flex use the ResourceManager.